# Understanding Java Course Assignment

Tags: java, image, bluej

[Assignment Instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO8xN.png)

I'm not sure what this means or what it is asking me to do, I've been programming with Java for only a few months and this seems really difficult with my limited knowledge.

Comment: Your course instructor might be a better person to ask than us.

Comment: You might also ask a question when asking a question, so that we know what/where to help you with... please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Comment: Thank you guys, sorry for not being specific but the only reason I didn't ask my instructor was the course is just executed poorly, but thanks for the input, Bautista answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, your assignment is to draw graphics on a panel using the required methods. The graphics can be of any color or size. Once you have done that, you are to make 3 copies of that panel which will leave you with 4 of the same panel. Then you are to put those 4 panels onto another panel and make a copy of that panel 3 times. This in reality should leave you with 16 of the original panels placed into a 4x4 grid or 4 big panels placed in a 2x2 grid. I would still recommend asking your instructor for help though, incase I am incorrect.